# DrlDumper not found on upgrading drools-compiler version

Tags: java, maven, drools, kie

I am changing my drools-compiler version from 7.40.0 to 7.60.0 but I am getting error that DrlDumper class not found.
I am unable to use dump method which is used to generate the drl files as DrlDumper.dump() method is used to do that.

Here is the code which used to create drl but not working on upgrading the drools-compiler and drools-core version:

```
String parsedRule = new DrlDumper().dump(packageDescrBuilder.getDescr());
```

Comment: DrlDumper was deprecated in 7.45.0, but the [javadocs](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.drools/drools-compiler/7.45.0.Final/index.html) don't indicate a substitute

Comment: Is there any way I can generate a drl file with a similar method like drlDumper?

Answer (score 0):

In 7.60+ `DrlDumper` is no longer part of the `drools-compiler` artifact and instead can be found in `drools-mvel`.

The java package has also moved to `org.drools.mvel`